# css - embed font both for IE and FF

Tags: css, font-face

I'm trying to embed a font, the problem is that it is just displayed in Firefox but not with Internet Explorer.

```
@font-face {
font-family: capture_it;
src: url('fonts/Capture_it.eot');
src: local('Comfortaa_it'),
    url('fonts/Capture_it.ttf') format('truetype'); 
}
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks,

enne

Comment: Which version of IE? For older versions, you will need something like [this hack](http://readableweb.com/mo-bulletproofer-font-face-css-syntax/).

Comment: Aktually for the latest IE, V9 I think.

Comment: IE9? Check if it's a CORS problem. Are the fonts served from the same domain?

Comment: IE9+ can handle .woff fonts, usually smaller than .ttf fonts. I'd recommend using the bulletpoint syntax with eot, woff2, woff, ttf, svg

Comment: Make sure you add the correct mime types to your apache/nginx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Font-face syntax is tricky, particularly with IE. Please use the one we developed here, which is cross-browser tested. http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax

It looks like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Different browsers support different font formats. You can generate all formats for optimal crossbrowser support with http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator.

The following is from the table found on the url included above:

**TTF**: Raw TrueType file, designed to look good on-screen.

**EOT Lite**: EOTs are only supported by Internet Explorer. This EOT type is uncompressed and is the same filesize as a TTF.

**EOT Compressed**: EOT compressed with LZ compression. File sizes are often smaller than WOFF.

**WOFF**: Cross-browser, web-only font format that uses gzip compression. IE9+, FF3.6+, Chrome 5+

**SVG**: This is an XML format required by iOS devices before version 4.2.

**SVGZ**: This is gzipped version of SVG.

Comment: Which browsers support EOT Lite and which EOT Compressed? Which of these two styles should be chosen at fontsquirrel.com to generate font that would be supported by as many browsers as possible? Is there some browser that support EOT Compressed format, but not EOT Lite or vice versa?

Comment: From what I gather, compressed has same compatibility than lite.

Comment: It doesn't look like fontsquirrel generates EOT fonts. How do we get a custom font to work on IE without those?

Comment: @jenlampton: Fontsquirrel has an "expert" option that allows you to add EOT.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use Google Fonts. If you can find one close enough to the one you want to use they're a really easy, quick and cross browser font solution. Moving away from Cufon to Google Fonts was a fantastic idea.

Well worth a look - http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace:select

Answer (score 0):

not exactly but close:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
 font-family: MyWebFont;
 src: url("font.eot") /* EOT file for IE (tested with ie8 and ie9)*/
}
@font-face {
 font-family: MyWebFont;
 src: url("font.ttf") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
</style>
```

and make the eot file from: http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi